# jQuery declaring function in noConflict environment

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to use $ instead of jQuery inside of declared function, that is not inside of jQuery(document).ready when in noConflict??

Sample code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.button').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        some_function($(this));
        return false;
    });
});

function some_function(el) {
    var id = jQuery(el).attr('href');
}
```

I would love to use $ instead of jQuery inside some_function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function some_function(el) {
    var $ = jQuery;
    var id = $(el).attr('href);
}
```

but at that rate, why bother with `$.noConflict`?

Comment: Becouse its a part of a bigger project, and: "Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Window] is not a function" ;). But the answer is correct :)